# Qt: make view to update visible data

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, model, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

In my program I use `QTableView` and `QAbstractTableModel` that are connected. Model doesn't contain data. When view needs data to show it calls `QAbstractTableModel::data` and model uses another object to get data and return. At some point data in that object is going changed. Model doesn't know what has changed so `dataChanged` is not called.

I need that only visible part of data (that is shown in view) goes updated. It should get new data from model. I am trying to achieve that by calling `update()` or `repaint()` functions of view but it doesn't help. I am thinking that it should call `paintEvent` of tableview but it is not called.

How is it possible to make view update visible part of data? I don't want to update whole data  that is huge.

Comment: You might try to emit `layoutChanged()` signal in your model. The signal has other purpose, but effect could be what you expect.

Comment: Why don't you just use a model which only represents displayed data?

Comment: @FinalContest Data is big and is stored in database that doesn't know about GUI or model/view. If I store copy also in model it will be data duplication and will use a lot memory. Instead I use some objects that fetch data from database to model if needed for view.

Answer (score 0):

Your wishes brokes Qt MVC logic. But if you need workaround - you may do next call to update visible area: `emit dataChanged( QModelIndex(), QModelIndex() );`